# Passing a link param to controller in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, parameters, request, laravel-5.3

I am trying to send a link to my controller. The problem is, a link contains slashes and therefore cannot be sent as a param because it will return the page not found error. I tried to encode the link to base64 but base64 also can contain slashes and therefore doesn't worth either. What is the best way to get pass this problem?

Routing

```
Route::get('/report/genealogy/{page}', 'ReportController@indexgenealogy');
```

HTML| $nextpage, returns: https://mywebsite.com/thisnewpage

```
<a href="./{{$nextpage}}">Next</a>
```

Controller

```
public function indexgenealogy($page)
{
    echo $page;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pass it as a query string parameter, and not a route parameter. Then you can url encode it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) to encode URI and then [`rawurldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php) to decode it.

Alternatively, you can pass it as a form parameter using `Route::post()` route:

```
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="some/url/with/slashes">
```

And get it in a controller:

```
public function someMethod(Request $request)
{
    $url = $request->url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the **url()** helper function?

```
//its as simple as
<a href="{{url('/report/genealogy/'.$nextPage)}}">next</a>
```

This will give you a proper url compatible with your route.

Comment: You're missing the point. That will just produce a link that leads to: http://localhost/report/genealogy/https://mywebsite.com/thisnewpage . Which will then reach a no page found error. Because of the forward slashes in the $nextpage link.

Comment: Besides that the question is not about how I'm trying to route my users to different views and such. It's asking how to pass a url to a controller.

Comment: ah i see. use it as a query string in that case. something like url?page=urlencoded value or as a hidden input form.

Answer (score 0):

Using named routes can help you with something like this

Routes:

```
Route::get('some/link/{link}' [
    'as' => 'pages.link',
    'uses' => 'controller@function'
]);
```

Then inside the view you can call it as follow:

```
<a href="{{ route('pages.link', ['link' => $nextpage]) }}">Next page</a>
```